# Datanucleus: JDO Deprecated field (do not create, read if exists)

Tags: metadata, jdo, deprecated, datanucleus

Scenario: A Field is deprecated.

Is it possible to map the field in a way that:

- It's not created in the database even if "datanucleus.autoCreateColumns" is set to TRUE (override by field attribute)
- It's loaded from the database (if exists)

Thanks

Comment: Slightly off-topic question, does such thing exist in other ORM frameworks ?